# Is there a way to right click on an item in Visual Studio and go straight to the documentation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, documentation

In my specific case I'm trying to go to the documentation of ostream in this example here:

```
class Frame
{
    string fileName;
    vector<Display> displays;
public:
    Frame::Frame(string s, vector<Display> d) :fileName(s), displays(d) {}
    Frame operator+(Frame&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Frame&);
};
```

If I hover over

> ostream&

it does give me some info. If I right click on it however it doesn't give me any option to go to the official documentation.

Is there a way to do this? I already downloaded all the documentation in the help browser but no way to conveniently look something up from the editor by right clicking on it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 community (for school purposes).

Comment: I believe this is they way you want to roll it miniuri.com/1bl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be done with the mouse as far as I'm aware but if the cursor is on a bit of code and you hit F1 the help for that item will be shown.

Comment: @Nomnom please indicate that by clicking the checkmark by this answer.